# restoring original data from jquery dialog, scripts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am creating a dialog box in jQuery and using the following suggestion to clear out the data on hitting the cancel button.

```
// store the old content
var myOldContent = $("#cancelbutton").html();

// change content
$("#cancelbutton").html(someNewContent);

// and change it back
$("#cancelbutton").html(myOldContent);
```

The problem is that this method clears out the data but I am using two inputs that don't work after the info is cleared.

I have a calendar input (called to an external .js) and a colorPicker, also initialized in an external .js.

How can i clear out the data without losing the functionality of these two components?

Comment: Do you have some event listeners on the two inputs ?

Comment: the calendar uses the datepicker ui from jQuery and the colorpicker has event listeners for capturing the events: selectorParent = $(event.target).parents("#" + selector.attr('id')).length;

            if (event.target === $(selector)[0] || event.target === selectorOwner[0] || selectorParent > 0) {
                return;
            }

            $.fn.colorPicker.hidePalette();

Comment: the calendar is initialized with the values chosen on the input (date from - date to) and has a beforeShow function call..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `.html()` that just takes the html itself not the actual DOM objects that have event listeners and data in them.

My recommendation would be to do something like this, although it could be done a lot of different ways depending on your layout:

```
// store the old content
var myOldContent = $("#cancelbutton").clone(true);  // 'true' so events are copied

// change content
$("#cancelbutton").html(someNewContent);

// bind new events for the newContent here

// and change it back
$("#cancelbutton").replaceWith(myOldContent);
```

Comment: Wait, did you mean input tags?  In that case just doing `$("input").val("")` will clear them out.